# How to do a single image inference using a trained CNN model (torch7 format)?

Tags: torch, conv-neural-network

I have obtained a trained CNN model in torch7 format.

How can I use that already trained model to run inference on a single image and return predictions, similar to [this](https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/7_imagenet_classification/classify.lua)?

Answer (score 0):

1. you need use torch.load function by given filepath to load your model, for example: `model = torch.load("/tmp/youmodel.t7")`
2. then load your image, for example: `img = image.load("/tmp/yourimage.png")`
3. check that the img size is same to your model's input, if they are different, you may use image resize function to make the img to the size you want, see more from https://github.com/torch/image
4. using forward function to get the prediction,for example: `res = model:forward(img)`